# EXCEL - US and EU number format in one sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel spreadsheet and there are two tables in one sheet. I need to have one table formatted as EU (decimal separator "," and thousand separator " ") and the second one as US (decimal separator "." and thousand separator ","). Lets say the source number is 765849739,88345 and in EU table I need "765 849 739,88" and in US table "765,849,739.88". Also consider that I can not predict the system settings of the final user. Any suggestions? Formula, format, VBA, anything? Thank you in advance

Comment: Will the data **source** always be using the EU format, as you show?  Why do you require two tables in different formats?  What have you tried?

Comment: FYI - you can get the regional settings if that helps. Worst case scenario is you could format cells via code, but you may be able to use 'conditional formatting'..

Comment: Data source should be in EU format. But to make sure of that I thought that for the beginning I change the system separators to make sure they will be in appropriate format (application.usesytemseparators, application.decimalseparator, application.thousandsseparator). And why I need it? One excel is linked to two words and each of them is in different language and the tables used within words should have formats used within that country.

Comment: I don't know any way you will be able to both format the table, and have it maintain the actual value if there is a decimal portion.  If, by *word*, you mean *Microsoft Word*, I suggest you keep the numbers in Excel as "real" numbers; and do the appropriate formatting within your *Word* document.

Comment: If you want to run some code to set the format, take a look at the following -- it goes both directions.... https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3785-excel-convert-european-number-to-us.html

Comment: Cool. Thats helping. I just switch first to separator I need and than I can adjust the formula. Thank you ;)